# Paint method throwing System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to prevent memory leak when repainting `PictureBox`

That's how my drawing method looks like:

```
Bitmap image; 
image = new Bitmap((Bitmap)baseImage.Clone());
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
//here I'm drawing using created "g"
//reason why am doing it on new bitmap, not on paintBox.Image is that.. 
//..I don't want this drawings to be permanently added to my base image
g.Dispose();
paintBox.Image = image;
```

Then I'm using method which is changing baseImage and refreshing paintBox many times (hundreds).
Calling this method gives me 'System.OutOfMemoryException' in System.Drawing.dll
This method is recursive, however I'm pretty sure it's not causing this exception, because  when I'm changing this method to only modify base image without refreshing paint box it works fine (however I would like to see changes it's making up to date).

So, what's the best method to prevent memory leak in this case?
I was trying something like this:

```
paintBoxx.Image.Dispose();
paintBox.Image = image;
```

but it is giving me 'System.NullReferenceException' (because I'm trying to use disposed image).

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to add `if (paintBox.Image != null) paintBox.Image.Dispose()`  before assigning the ne one, ie after `g.Dispose` in the first block of code..

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works well.

Comment: I thought that _System.NullReferenceException_ was caused by calling _paintBox.Image = image;_ after disposing it, however turned out that the problem was caused by calling _dispose_ before any image was added to paintBox.

Comment: Both are errors you should avoid.

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Comment: In this case, yes. Still don't know why `using` wont work though.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
Bitmap image; 


image = new Bitmap((Bitmap)baseImage.Clone());

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image) )
{
   // I am drawing on the bitmap so I don't permanently change my base image
   // do your draw stuff here..
   g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Yellow, 3, 3, 9, 9);
   // ..  
}
// don't leak the image and..
// ..don't Dispose without checking for null
if (paintBox.Image != null) paintBox.Image.Dispose();
paintBox.Image = image;
```

Note the `using` clause, which will dispose of the `Graphics` object, even if the drawing runs into problems.

Comment: For some reason this solution is giving me both: _arg exception_ and _out of memory exception_, while `g.Dispose()` worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using MemoryStream?

Take a look at my example code:

```
image = new Bitmap((Bitmap)baseImage.Clone());
using (MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    // put iimagem in memory stream
    image.Save(imageStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);

    // create an array of bytes with image length
    byte[] imageContent = new Byte[imageStream.Length];

    // reset memory stream
    imageStream.Position = 0;

    // load array of bytes with the imagem
    imageStream.Read(imageContent, 0, (int)imageStream.Length);

    // change header page "content-type" to "image/jpeg" and print the image.
    Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
    Response.BinaryWrite(imageContent);
}
```